# Getting crash after implements OnMapReadyCallback

Tags: android, android-activity

After I have implemented the OnMapReadyCallback the activity which the app uses for posting an add crashes, before implements activity worked good. I have add all that the OnMapReadyCallBackRequest, but I don't know why it crashes.

```
package com.classify.activity;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.provider.MediaStore.MediaColumns;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ScrollView;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.classify.activity.adapters.CatItem;
import com.classify.activity.adapters.CatePriseAdapter;
import com.classify.activity.adapters.CateSpinnerAdapter;
import com.classify.activity.adapters.cateCityAdapter;
import com.classify.activity.utils.AndroidMultiPartEntity;
import com.classify.activity.utils.Constants;
import com.classify.activity.utils.CustomProgressDialog;
import com.classify.activity.utils.GeocodeJSONParser;
import com.classify.activity.utils.GetJSONObject;
import com.classify.activity.utils.MarshMallowPermission;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.UiSettings;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.FileBody;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.StringBody;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class AddPostActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements   OnMapReadyCallback{

private GoogleMap map;
ArrayList<CatItem>cateList = new ArrayList<CatItem>();
private Spinner spiCategory,spiCity,spiPrice;
ImageView imgadpost1,imgadpost2,imgadpost3;
private String selectedImagePath1 = "";
private String selectedImagePath2 = "";
private String selectedImagePath3 = "";
final private int PICK_IMAGE1 = 11;
final private int CAPTURE_IMAGE1 = 21;
final private int PICK_IMAGE2 = 12;
final private int CAPTURE_IMAGE2 = 22;
final private int PICK_IMAGE3 = 13;
final private int CAPTURE_IMAGE3 = 23;
private String imgPath;
View imageView;
CateSpinnerAdapter adapter;
cateCityAdapter adapterCity;

TextView txtTitle,txtCategory,txtPrice,txtDesc,txtAddress,txtspinnercategory,txtcontact,txtSpinnerCity,txtSpiPrice;
EditText edttitle,edtprice,edtdescription,edtaddrerss,edtcontact;
private UiSettings mUiSettings;
ScrollView  scrollViewParent;
ImageView imgMap;

Toolbar toolbar;
Typeface typeface,typeface1;

Button btnPostAdd;
String strtitle = "",strprice="",strdescription="",straddress= "",advertId="",strcontact="",strCity="";
int categoryId = -1;
private double lat = 0.0;
private double lng =0.0;
private SharedPreferences pref;
private AdView mAdView;
private InterstitialAd mInterstitial;
MarshMallowPermission marshMallowPermission;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.add_post_activity);

    MapFragment fm = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.maps_fragment);
    fm.getMapAsync(this);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/GandhiSerif-Bold.otf");

    if (toolbar != null) {
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle(R.string.AddPost);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
    getActionBarTextView();

    marshMallowPermission = new MarshMallowPermission(this);
    if (!marshMallowPermission.checkPermissionForExternalStorage()) {
        marshMallowPermission.requestPermissionForExternalStorage();
    }
    if (!marshMallowPermission.checkPermissionForCamera()) {
        marshMallowPermission.requestPermissionForCamera();
    }
    if (!marshMallowPermission.checkPermissionForCoreLocation()) {
        marshMallowPermission.requestPermissionForCoreLocation();
    }
    if (!marshMallowPermission.checkPermissionForfineLocation()) {
        marshMallowPermission.requestPermissionForfineLocation();
    }
    mAdView = (AdView)findViewById(R.id.adView);
    mAdView.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());

    pref = getSharedPreferences("loginpreference", MODE_PRIVATE);
    advertId = pref.getString("advertId","");

    spiCategory = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spiCategory);
    spiCity = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spiCity);
    spiPrice = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spiPrice);

    imgadpost1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgadpost1);
    imgadpost2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgadpost2);
    imgadpost3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgadpost3);
    imgMap     = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgmap);

    txtAddress = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtAddress);
    txtCategory= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtCategory);
    txtDesc    = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtDesc);
    txtPrice   = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtPrice);
    txtTitle   = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
    txtcontact = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtContact);
    txtSpinnerCity = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtspinnercity);
    txtSpiPrice = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtSpiPrice);


    edtdescription = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtdescription);
    edtprice  = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtprice);
    edttitle = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edttitle);
    edtaddrerss = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtaddrerss);
    edtcontact  = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtcontact);
    
    
    btnPostAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPostAdd);
    txtspinnercategory = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtspinnercategory);

    scrollViewParent = (ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.scrollView);
    View customView = (View)findViewById(R.id.customView);


    txtAddress.setTypeface(typeface);
    txtCategory.setTypeface(typeface);
    txtDesc.setTypeface(typeface);
    txtPrice.setTypeface(typeface);
    txtTitle.setTypeface(typeface);
    txtcontact.setTypeface(typeface);

    edtaddrerss.setTypeface(typeface);
    edtdescription.setTypeface(typeface);
    edtprice.setTypeface(typeface);
    edttitle.setTypeface(typeface);
    btnPostAdd.setTypeface(typeface);
    edtcontact.setTypeface(typeface);

    cateList = new ArrayList<CatItem>();
    new GetCategoryList().execute();

    txtspinnercategory.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            spiCategory.performClick();
        }
    });
    spiCategory.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            if (cateList.size() > 0) {
                txtspinnercategory.setText(cateList.get(position).toString());
                categoryId = cateList.get(position).getId();
            }

        }
        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });

    imgadpost1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            imageView = v;
            startDialog(1); 
        }
    });

    imgadpost2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            imageView = v;
            startDialog(2); 
        }
    });
    imgadpost3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            imageView = v;
            startDialog(3); 
        }
    });


    ArrayList<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    list1.add("Berat");
    list1.add("Bulqizë");
    list1.add("Delvinë");
    list1.add("Devoll");
    list1.add("Dibër");
    list1.add("Durrës");
    list1.add("Elbasan");
    list1.add("Fier");
    list1.add("Gramsh");
    list1.add("Gjirokastër");
    list1.add("Has");
    list1.add("Kavajë");
    list1.add("Kolonjë");
    list1.add("Korçë");
    list1.add("Krujë");
    list1.add("Kucovë");
    list1.add("Kukës");
    list1.add("Kurbin");
    list1.add("Lezhë");
    list1.add("Librazhd");
    list1.add("Lushnjë");
    list1.add("Malësi e Madhe");
    list1.add("Mallakastër");
    list1.add("Mat");
    list1.add("Mirditë");
    list1.add("Peqin");
    list1.add("Përmet");
    list1.add("Pogradec");
    list1.add("Pukë");
    list1.add("Sarandë");
    list1.add("Skrapar");
    list1.add("Shkodër");
    list1.add("Tepelenë");
    list1.add("Tiranë");
    list1.add("Tropojë");
    list1.add("Vlorë");


    adapterCity = new cateCityAdapter(this,list1,typeface);
    spiCity.setAdapter(adapterCity);

    txtSpinnerCity.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            spiCity.performClick();
        }
    });
    spiCity.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            txtSpinnerCity.setText(parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString());

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });

    ArrayList<String> currencyArray = new ArrayList<String>();
    currencyArray.add("EUR");
    currencyArray.add("LEK");

    CatePriseAdapter adapterPrice = new CatePriseAdapter(this,currencyArray,typeface);
    spiPrice.setAdapter(adapterPrice);

    txtSpiPrice.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            spiPrice.performClick();
        }
    });
    spiPrice.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            txtSpiPrice.setText(parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString());

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });

    btnPostAdd.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            
            mInterstitial = new InterstitialAd(getApplicationContext());
            mInterstitial.setAdUnitId(getResources().getString(R.string.interestrial_id));
            mInterstitial.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());

            mInterstitial.setAdListener(new AdListener() 
            {
                @Override
                public void onAdLoaded() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    super.onAdLoaded();
                    //mInterstitial.show();
                }
            });
            
            String strPriceCurrency= txtSpiPrice.getText().toString();

            strtitle = edttitle.getText().toString().trim();
            strprice = edtprice.getText().toString().trim() + strPriceCurrency;
            straddress = edtaddrerss.getText().toString().trim();
            strdescription = edtdescription.getText().toString().trim();
            strcontact  = edtcontact.getText().toString().trim();
            strCity = txtSpinnerCity.getText().toString().trim();

            edttitle.setError(null);
            edtprice.setError(null);
            edtaddrerss.setError(null);
            edtdescription.setError(null);
            edtcontact.setError(null);

            if(strtitle.length() == 0){
                edttitle.requestFocus();
                edttitle.setError("Enter title.");
            }else if(strprice.length() == 0){
                edtprice.requestFocus();
                edtprice.setError("Enter price.");
            }else if(straddress.length() == 0){
                edtaddrerss.requestFocus();
                edtaddrerss.setError("Enter address.");
            }else if(strdescription.length() == 0){
                edtdescription.requestFocus();
                edtdescription.setError("Enter description.");
            }else if(selectedImagePath1.length() == 0 & selectedImagePath2.length() ==0 && selectedImagePath3.length() == 0){
                Toast.makeText(AddPostActivity.this,"Please select images.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }else if(categoryId == -1){
                Toast.makeText(AddPostActivity.this,"Please select Category.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }else if(lat == 0.0 && lng == 0.0){
                Toast.makeText(AddPostActivity.this,"Please insert location.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }else if(strcontact.length() == 0){
                edtcontact.requestFocus();
                edtcontact.setError("Enter Contact Number.");
            }else{
                new PostAddTask().execute();
            }
        }
    });

    imgMap.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            String location = edtaddrerss.getText().toString();

            if(location==null || location.equals("")){
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No Place is entered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }

            String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?";

            try {
                // encoding special characters like space in the user input place
                location = URLEncoder.encode(location, "utf-8");
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            String address = "address=" + location;
            String sensor = "sensor=false";
            url = url + address + "&" + sensor;
            DownloadTask downloadTask = new DownloadTask();
            downloadTask.execute(url);
        }
    });

    customView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            int action = event.getAction();
            switch (action) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                // Disallow ScrollView to intercept touch events.
                scrollViewParent.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                // Disable touch on transparent view
                return false;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                // Allow ScrollView to intercept touch events.
                scrollViewParent.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                return true;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                scrollViewParent.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                return false;

            default:
                return true;
            }
        }
    });

}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if(id==android.R.id.home)
    {
        onBackPressed();
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onBackPressed();

}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {


    map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
    mUiSettings = map.getUiSettings();

    mUiSettings.setCompassEnabled(true);
    mUiSettings.setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);

}

class PostAddTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
{
    String jsonStr = null;
    CustomProgressDialog cd = new CustomProgressDialog();

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        cd.showdialog(AddPostActivity.this, "Loading...");
    }
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        jsonStr = uploadFile();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        cd.dismissdialog();

        if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
                String responce = jsonObj.getString(Constants.LOGIN_TAG);
                String msg = jsonObj.getString(Constants.REG_TAG);
          
                
                Toast.makeText(AddPostActivity.this, "successfully Ad posted",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
        }
        
        Intent intent = new Intent(AddPostActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        
        

    }
}

private String uploadFile() {
    String responseString = null;
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(Constants.WEBURL);

    try {
        AndroidMultiPartEntity entity = new AndroidMultiPartEntity(new AndroidMultiPartEntity.ProgressListener() {

            @Override
            public void transferred(long num) {

            }
        });
        if(selectedImagePath1.length()>0){
            File file = new File(selectedImagePath1);
            entity.addPart("images[]", new FileBody(file));
        }
        if(selectedImagePath2.length()>0){
            File file = new File(selectedImagePath2);
            entity.addPart("images[]", new FileBody(file));
        }
        if(selectedImagePath2.length()>0){
            File file = new File(selectedImagePath2);
            entity.addPart("images[]", new FileBody(file));
        }
        entity.addPart("action", new StringBody("postAd"));
        entity.addPart("advertId", new StringBody(advertId));
        entity.addPart("categoryId", new StringBody(String.valueOf(categoryId)));
        entity.addPart("title", new StringBody(strtitle));
        entity.addPart("prize", new StringBody(strprice));
        entity.addPart("city",new StringBody(strCity));
        entity.addPart("desc", new StringBody(strdescription));
        entity.addPart("address", new StringBody(straddress));
        entity.addPart("contact",new StringBody(strcontact));
        entity.addPart("latlong", new StringBody(String.valueOf(lat)+","+String.valueOf(lng)));
        entity.addPart("info",new StringBody("Hellooo"));

        httppost.setEntity(entity);

        // Making server call
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity r_entity = response.getEntity();

        int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        if (statusCode == 200) {
            // Server response
            responseString = EntityUtils.toString(r_entity);
            Log.e("PostAd", "Response:"+responseString);
        } else {
            responseString = "Error occurred! Http Status Code: "+ statusCode;
        }

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        responseString = e.toString();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        responseString = e.toString();
    }

    return responseString;

}
private TextView getActionBarTextView() {
    TextView titleTextView = null;

    try {
        Field f = toolbar.getClass().getDeclaredField("mTitleTextView");
        f.setAccessible(true);
        titleTextView = (TextView)f.get(toolbar);
        titleTextView.setTypeface(typeface);

    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
    }
    return titleTextView;
}

class GetCategoryList extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
{

    String jsonStr = null;
    JSONObject jsonObj = null;
    CustomProgressDialog cd = new CustomProgressDialog();

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        cd.showdialog(AddPostActivity.this, "Loading.....");

    }
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        jsonObj = new GetJSONObject().getJSONfromURL(Constants.CAT_URL);
        Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        cd.dismissdialog();

        if (jsonObj != null) {
            try {
                JSONArray contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray(Constants.TAG);
                for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);
                    String id = c.getString(Constants.CAT_ID);
                    String name = c.getString(Constants.CAT_NAME);

                    CatItem v=new CatItem();
                    v.setId(Integer.parseInt(id));
                    v.setName(name);
                    cateList.add(v);

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            adapter = new CateSpinnerAdapter(AddPostActivity.this, cateList,typeface);
            spiCategory.setAdapter(adapter);
        } else {
            Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
        }

    }
}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
        Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        if(requestCode == PICK_IMAGE1 || requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE1){
            if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE1) {
                selectedImagePath1 = getAbsolutePath(data.getData());
                ImageView img=(ImageView)imageView;
                img.setImageBitmap(decodeFile(selectedImagePath1));
            } else if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE1) {
                selectedImagePath1 = getImagePath();
                ImageView img=(ImageView)imageView;
                img.setImageBitmap(decodeFile(selectedImagePath1));
            }
        }else if(requestCode == PICK_IMAGE2 || requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE2){
            if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE2) {
                selectedImagePath2 = getAbsolutePath(data.getData());
                ImageView img=(ImageView)imageView;
                img.setImageBitmap(decodeFile(selectedImagePath2));
            } else if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE2) {
                selectedImagePath2 = getImagePath();
                ImageView img=(ImageView)imageView;
                img.setImageBitmap(decodeFile(selectedImagePath2));
            }
        }else if(requestCode == PICK_IMAGE3 || requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE3){
            if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE3) {
                selectedImagePath3 = getAbsolutePath(data.getData());
                ImageView img=(ImageView)imageView;
                img.setImageBitmap(decodeFile(selectedImagePath3));
            } else if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE3) {
                selectedImagePath3 = getImagePath();
                ImageView img=(ImageView)imageView;
                img.setImageBitmap(decodeFile(selectedImagePath3));
            }
        }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode,data);

    }
}

private void startDialog(final int imageid)
{
    android.app.AlertDialog.Builder builder = new android.app.AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Upload Pictures Option");
    builder.setMessage("How do you want to set your picture?");
    builder.setPositiveButton("Gallery", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialoginterface, int i)
        {
            if(imageid == 1) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, ""), PICK_IMAGE1);
            }else if(imageid == 2){
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, ""),PICK_IMAGE2);
            }else if(imageid == 3){
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, ""),PICK_IMAGE3);
            }
        }

    });
    builder.setNegativeButton("Camera", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialoginterface, int i)
        {
            if(imageid == 1) {
                final Intent intent = new Intent(
                        MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                        setImageUri());
                startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE1);
            }else if(imageid ==2){
                final Intent intent = new Intent(
                        MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                        setImageUri());
                startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE2);
            }else if(imageid == 3){
                final Intent intent = new Intent(
                        MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                        setImageUri());
                startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE3);
            }
        }
    });
    builder.show();
}
public Uri setImageUri() {
    // Store image in dcim
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()  + "/DCIM/", "image" + new Date().getTime() + ".png");
    Uri imgUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
    this.imgPath = file.getAbsolutePath();
    return imgUri;
}

public String getImagePath() {
    return imgPath;
}

public Bitmap decodeFile(String path) {
    try {
        // Decode image size
        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, o);
        // The new size we want to scale to
        final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 70;

        // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of
        // 2.
        int scale = 1;
        while (o.outWidth / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE
                && o.outHeight / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE)
            scale *= 2;

        // Decode with inSampleSize
        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o2.inSampleSize = scale;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, o2);
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;

}

public String getAbsolutePath(Uri uri) {
    String[] projection = { MediaColumns.DATA };
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    if (cursor != null) {
        int column_index = cursor
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaColumns.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    } else
        return null;
}

private String downloadUrl(String strUrl) throws IOException{
    String data = "";
    InputStream iStream = null;
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    try{
        URL url = new URL(strUrl);
        // Creating an http connection to communicate with url
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        // Connecting to url
        urlConnection.connect();

        // Reading data from url
        iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));

        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

        String line = "";
        while( ( line = br.readLine()) != null){
            sb.append(line);
        }

        data = sb.toString();
        br.close();

    }catch(Exception e){
        //Log.d("Exception while downloading url", e.toString());
    }finally{
        iStream.close();
        urlConnection.disconnect();
    }

    return data;
}
private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>
{
    String data = null;
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... url) {
        try{
            data = downloadUrl(url[0]);
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.d("Background Task",e.toString());
        }
        return data;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result){

        ParserTask parserTask = new ParserTask();
        parserTask.execute(result);
    }
}
class ParserTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, List<HashMap<String,String>>>{

    JSONObject jObject;
    @Override
    protected List<HashMap<String,String>> doInBackground(String... jsonData) {

        List<HashMap<String, String>> places = null;
        GeocodeJSONParser parser = new GeocodeJSONParser();

        try{
            jObject = new JSONObject(jsonData[0]);

            places = parser.parse(jObject);

        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.d("Exception",e.toString());
        }
        return places;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<HashMap<String,String>> list){
        map.clear();

        for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++){

            HashMap<String, String> hmPlace = list.get(i);
            lat = Double.parseDouble(hmPlace.get("lat"));
            lng = Double.parseDouble(hmPlace.get("lng"));
            String name = hmPlace.get("formatted_address");

            LatLng l1 = new LatLng(lat,lng);
            MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions();
            options.position(l1);
            options.title(name);
            options.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN));
            map.addMarker(options);
            map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(l1, 10));
        }
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your map instance is null, and when you received callback you have nullpointerexception.

try to do next

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
map = googleMap;
map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
.... 
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, you have helped me. Thank you !